# Spring Security, Rest Authentication and CSRF

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I would like use authentication with my application. 
I hava a Spring MVC app and Spring Security applied. Against browser, it is working fine.
It means, I authenticate a user to my app and use web page.

Now, I want to use rest. I added on my unsecure controller method @ResponseBody and I receive response in json.
But how to connect to my application with user and password with RestTemplate ?

My code in RestClient is (for test) :

```
public void unsecureProfileTest() {

    String url = articleServiceUrl + "unsecure/profile/test.json";
    url = articleServiceUrl + "secure/profile/wiew.json";
    HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(getHeaders("user:userpassword"));
    Object s = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Object.class);

}

static HttpHeaders getHeaders(String auth) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
            MediaType.TEXT_HTML));

    byte[] encodedAuthorisation = Base64.encode(auth.getBytes());
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic "
            + new String(encodedAuthorisation));

    return headers;
}
```

My SecurityConfig :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").permitAll().and()
            .formLogin().successHandler(successHandler)
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/").failureHandler(failureHandler)
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true").permitAll().and().logout()
            .permitAll();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/unsecure/**").permitAll();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/secure/*").authenticated();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

The result is : Access is denied. 
I guess the problem comming from authentication from restTemplate but how can I authenticate ?

My second question is regarding csrf who is disabled but I want to enable it (my forms use it)

I'm using Spring 4.0 and Spring Security 3.2

***EDIT***
I updated my code with

```
String url = articleServiceUrl + "unsecure/profile/test.json";
url = articleServiceUrl + "secure/profile/wiew.json";
HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(getHeaders("{user:userpassword, password:userpassword}"));
Object s = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Object.class);
```

I receive a code `302`

***EDIT 18022014 - 16:46***
I updated to

```
String url = articleServiceUrl + "login?username=user&password=userpassword";
HttpEntity entity restTemplate;exchange(url, HTTPMethod.POST,null, HttpEntity.class)
system.out.println(entity);
```

In log of web server, I received a success message (see userdetails on "user").

*Now, I would like use authentication to access to other url ("secure/profile/view.json")*

How to keep authentication ?

Thank you

Comment: Form-based authentication isn't a good choice when you don't have an interactive login (and potentially no session). Consider using something like basic authentication instead.

Comment: I have an interactive login, because I have a website to manage users and a lot of things made by admins

Comment: Yes, but presumably that's a separate concern from the ReST API you're talking about in this question? Your best option is probably to define a separate, stateless filter chain for the ReST part. The form login configuration won't process a basic authentication header.

Comment: And now you want to allow to users use their names and passwords for login via basic auth? If yes, you need enable basic auth spring security filter and configure it for wotking with your user's DAO

Comment: No, I don't use really a Basic authentication but I extended UserDetailsService to use a DAO (with Spring Data JPA). The fact it is maybe I don't understand different authentication type.

Answer (score 3):

I have been playing with spring security and spring boot REST application and I created my own **MapCsrfTokenRepository** that I used instead of default **HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository**.

Then you can enable csrf for your rest URIs with

```
http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(tokenRepository)
```

The main idea is to return new CSRF_TOKEN when client access **/login** resource with **GET**, because no csrf token is needed for GET. And then client has to use this token in next calls.

Example is on [github](https://github.com/bassmake/CsrfRestExample)

Comment: Hi bsmk. so how does that make it Restful if you are stored the token to the repository?

Comment: It is not fully Restful. That is just trade-off, I am not sure if this is the right approach, but I haven't found anything else.